# How to submit android app for facebook review?

Tags: android, facebook, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network

I successfully integrated facebook audience network in my android app with admob mediation. My app is showing facebook's test ads. But I don't understand how to submit it for review. In app dashboard, there is an option to add items. which items should I select for mediation? My app doesn't have any login option. I just want to show Facebook and admob ads using mediation. 
[App link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tofabd.batteryanalyzer).
Please help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your `App Dashboard -> Products ->Audience Network`  from there you can see a link to `Monetization Manager`, you can see your app from there and can submit for review